# Firestore, adding value to an existing array field

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

I want the new ph value to be added in the arraylist but instead, it keep updating the first value of the arraylist

[my firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYJR7.png)

```
var insBtn = document.getElementById("InsBtn");

 async function AddDocument_CustomID() {
    var ref = doc(db,"pHvalue", "pH");

     await setDoc(
        ref, {
            pH: [pH.value]
        });
}


insBtn.addEventListener('click', AddDocument_CustomID);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new unique value to the existing values in the `pH` array, you can use an [`array-union` operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update_elements_in_an_array):

```
updateDoc(ref, {
    pH: arrayUnion(pH.value)
});
```

If you instead want to add a possibly non-unique value to the end of the `pH` array, you will instead have to:

1. Load the document into your application and get the existing `pH` array from it.
2. Add the new item to the end of the array.
3. Write the entire array back to the database.

Comment: that is perfect, thx alot